# int does not contain a definition for ToArray

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC app in which I have just updated my model, and now I'm getting this strange error message that I can't figure out.  Alls I did was update the model and save it, so something has updated something.

The error is:

```
'int' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found
```

Here is the line that's causing the error:

```
viewMaster.properties = _dbLazy.spPropertyByBuildingLookup(propString, null).ToArray();
```

And here is the spPropertyByBuildingLookup method (of course, it's based on a SP of the same name):

```
public virtual int spPropertyByBuildingLookup(string propertyInclude, string propertyExclude)
    {
        var propertyIncludeParameter = propertyInclude != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("propertyInclude", propertyInclude) :
            new ObjectParameter("propertyInclude", typeof(string));

        var propertyExcludeParameter = propertyExclude != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("propertyExclude", propertyExclude) :
            new ObjectParameter("propertyExclude", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("spPropertyByBuildingLookup", propertyIncludeParameter, propertyExcludeParameter);
    }
```

Comment: `spPropertyByBuildingLookup` is returning `ìnt` and then you're calling `ToArray()`. What did you expect?

Comment: There is obviously no extension method named `ToArray` avaiable on int.what is the data type of `viewMaster.properties`?

Comment: l19: Yeah, I get that.  The code you see above was written by someone else.  It worked fine until I updated my model, as I said.

Dark Knight: Properties is an object based on a data model.  I tried to use ObjectResult<Property>, which is what all the other similar methods use.  Updating the model has broken something for some reason, and if I can find out what it broke, I might be able to fix it.

Comment: I really don't understand why it's so hard to ask a question on this site without getting a bunch of smart-ass remarks from pretentious assholes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, essentially what I ended up doing was reverting the Model back to the way it was (we use GitHub for source control).  What happened was, I updated a field in the Property table from varchar to bit.  I had to delete the table from the model and re add it.  When I did, it defaulted the spPropertyByBuildingLookup method to return an int (it had to remove references to the Property model that was deleted).  I found this out by going into the CBA.Context.cs file after it was reverted to see what had changed.